# Why does Xcode say that "window" is a undeclared identifier?

Tags: xcode, window, uitabbarcontroller, subview, undeclared-identifier

I'm trying to write a simple application that switches between views using a Tab Bar.

I have used a guide from Apple's Developer Library: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW1

The problem is that when I write the code to add a subview:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    [window addSubview:myTabBarController.view];

}
```

it says that "window" is undeclared identifier.

What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

This should generally be `self.window` rather than `window` (there is a difference). But in any case, did you create a `window` ivar and wire it to the object this code comes from in Interface Builder? The templates do this automatically if you used one of the templates (and you should).

`applicationDidFinishLaunching:` is only applicable to the application delegate. Is this in the application delegate?